# psycopg2 connects, defines cursor but all request timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database with python, I connect just fine, and create cursor just fine. However, when I run any kind of query it gives me the following message:

`psycopg2.DatabaseError: could not receive data from server: Operation timed out`

This is a c4.xlarge ec2 instance. I have changed the port to 9200, and my configs allow the connection from my ip range. The code prints out the cursor and connection objects.

```
<connection object at 0x1085409d0; dsn: 'dbname=ecs user=masked password=xxxxxxx host=masked port=9200', closed: 0> <cursor object at 0x1085fcde0; closed: 0>
```

**Code:**

```
import psycopg2

print "Connecting to PostGres"
database_connection = psycopg2.connect(database="ecs", user="masked", password="masked", host="masked", port="9200")
database_cursor_1 = database_connection.cursor()
print database_connection, database_cursor_1
```

but when I run any query doesn't matter what it is I get the error message couldn't receive data operation timeout.

I'm on a mac. Postgres is running on CentOS.

Comment: It would help if you could provide full stacktrace and the code that run the query (maybe it's missing something)?

Comment: also configuration aws' vpc/subnet  would give some info

Comment: what happens if you execute a query using psql ?

Comment: the same thing @e4c5

Comment: nothing to do with pscycopg2 this is a firewall issue.